# Deploy django using apache, mod-wsgi

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy `django` using `wsgi`. But its not working. Will you please help me ? thank you

`django.wsgi.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/me/project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName www.me.org
  ServerAlias *me.org

  Alias /admin_media /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media

  <Location /admin_media>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  Alias /media /var/www/media/

  <Location /media>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/project/apache/django.wsgi

  WSGIDaemonProcess me processes=2 maximum-requests=500 threads=1
  WSGIProcessGroup me

</VirtualHost>
```

`Error Message`

```
   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/me:
Invalid command 'PythonHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

UPDATE :Strange `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/me`

```
<Location "/">
SetHandler python-program
PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
PythonDebug On
PythonPath "['/home/me2'] + sys.path"
SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE me.settings
```

Can I disable mod-python?

Comment: We're missing the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/me. Or is this a symlink to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/me` file is for modpython.

You're using mod_wsgi.

Therefore.  Remove the  `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/me` and follow the documentation provided here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: I've removed `/etc/apache2/sites-enable/me`. Now I'm getting. `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Comment: @no_access: That's a separate question.  Please open a **new** question providing the **relevant** details for your new problem.  You'll probably need to create an Apache "Location" that directs requests to your Django instance.  Please accept an answer to this question and start a new question that covers your new situation.

Answer (score 3):

It should be obvious that your error message is coming from a different file than the one you have shown here - `me` rather than `default`. That file apparently has a reference to `PythonHandler`, which is a directive that belongs to `mod_python` which you don't seem to have installed (and shouldn't, as it is deprecated).

When you've fixed that error - most likely by removing that file altogether - you'll have another one to fix in your `wsgi` file - you've added the `project` path to the pythonpath, but then referenced your settings as `project.settings`, so it won't be found. Either add the parent path instead, or reference settings as just `settings`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at this stuff, but here is comparing to what I've got working.  I'm using mod_wsgi instead of mod_python.  What you have in "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/me" I seem to have sepecified in my "django.wsgi.py" file, and I have no such files under sites-enabled.

To your django.wsgi.py you might need to add the path to your external libraries, and when I set the path for my project, my settings file is /var/myproject/src/myapp/settings.py, and I set the path to '/var/myproject/src', and the django_settings_module to myapp.settings.  Here's what my myproject.wsgi file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.3-py2.7.egg')
... other external libs ..
sys.path.append('/var/myproject/myapp/src')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myapp.settings'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Here is what I've got for my wsgi.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@me.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/myproject/"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "/var/myproject/logs/apache-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/myproject/logs/apache-access.log" common

    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess asgportal
    WSGIProcessGroup asgportal

    Alias /static /var/myproject/media/static
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/myproject/myproject.wsgi  # my django.wsgi.py file

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</VirtualHost>
```